# Do you use commas or full stops in a name

Tags: grammar

I am writing a name on a form and I was wondering whether it would be John.Tom.Smith or John,Tom,Smith

Comment: Neither. Use spaces: `John Tom Smith`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither, as long as you are putting the name in the natural order, Jon Tom Smith. If you are instructed to put the surname first, as in an index, then a comma after the surname, and the rest in the natural order: Smith, Jon Tom.